# Scope binding not working in modal popup angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html, twitter-bootstrap

I am using angular to bind data to my UI which works perfectly well. But when a modal popup is called on button click, the binding in the modal does not work.

[image]

```
<div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">{{checkItem}}</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button ng-click="saveClient()" class="btn btn-primary pull-right btn-tabkey"><i class="fa fa-save"></i>Save</button>&nbsp;&nbsp;
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="focusInput=false"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i>Cancel</button>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div>
```

Angular:

```
angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$filter", "dataService", function ($rootScope, $scope, $filter, dataService) {

    $scope.checkItem = "";

    $scope.loadEditForm = function () {
        $scope.checkItem = "yes";
        $("#modal-form-edit").modal();
    };


}]);
```

Comment: is the modal a directive? if so, directives get their own scope

Comment: It is not a directive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Seems like you are opening the modal using plain jQuery approach. This is not going to work in Angular, because opened modal is not connected to Angular application, so it doesn't know that modal has to be handled, HTML parsed, etc.

Instead you should use directives properly, or in case of modal dialog you can simply use existent ones, like Angular UI project, which brings ready Bootstrap directives for Angular. In your case you need [`$modal`](http://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/modal) service.

The usage then would be very simple:

```
// remember to add ui.bootstrap module dependency
angular.module('myModule', ['ui.bootstrap']); 

angular.module('myModule').controller('myController', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$filter", "$modal", "dataService", function ($rootScope, $scope, $filter, $modal, dataService) {

    $scope.checkItem = "";

    $scope.loadEditForm = function () {
        $scope.checkItem = "yes";
        $modal.open({
            templateUrl: 'modal.html',
            controller: 'modalController',
            scope: $scope
        });
    };

}]);
```

**Demo:** http://plnkr.co/edit/kQz0fiaXLv7T37N8fzJU?p=preview

Comment: what js file does `ui.bootstrap` reference?

Comment: Check updated answer, I added demo of how you should configure everything.

Comment: Hello @dfsq I forgot to include I am using .net MVC. How do I call partial views in `templateUrl`?

Comment: Not .NET expert, so can't answer this question. But you need to provide an URL for downloadble resource. Meaning that if you go in browser to this url it downloads template HTML file.

Answer (score 2):

You need to assign `ng-controller` in your modal-dialog  div tag.

```
<div class="modal-dialog" **ng-controller="myController"**>
.
.
.
.
.
```

### Update

I think you got this below error in your console window

***Module 'myModule' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.***

So please change `nangular.module('myModule')` to `angular.module('myModule',[])`

try this below js code instead of your code with my above changes

```
angular.module('myModule',[]).controller('myController', ["$rootScope", "$scope", "$filter", "dataService", function ($rootScope, $scope, $filter, dataService) {

    $scope.checkItem = "";

    $scope.loadEditForm = function () {
        $scope.checkItem = "yes";
        $("#modal-form-edit").modal();
    };


}]);
```

Comment: i think you got any console error, please verify it

Answer (score 0):

It is possible that your modal (e.g - bootstrap modal ) might be outside of the ng-controller directive